# Milliseconds to Seconds?

Tags: c#

Am trying to convert my string value(the value is millisecond value) from seconds.

Here is my code am trying to convert inside my xml append

```
xmlElement = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "duration", null);
//Convert Milliseconds to Seconds

string durationMilli=DurationValue[1].TrimStart();
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(durationMilli);//tried this didn't work
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(durationMilli).TotalSeconds;//then tried this didn't work either
xmlElement.InnerText = DurationValue[1].TrimStart();
newChild.AppendChild(xmlElement);
```

It's throwing:

> "The best Overloaded method match for System.Timespan.FromMilliseconds(double) has invalid arguments"

am not sure i have to convert the string to actual millisecond value then use timespan to convert to seconds ? please guide me.

Thanks in Advance.

Modified the code little bit and this what am using in my code (this is Answer)

```
  string durationMilli = DurationValue[1].TrimStart();
            double milliseconds;
            // Try to convert string to double
            if (double.TryParse(durationMilli, out milliseconds))
            {
                // milliseconds now contains your value
                double ds = Math.Round(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(milliseconds).TotalSeconds);
                string totalsec = ds.ToString();
                xmlElement.InnerText = totalsec;
                newChild.AppendChild(xmlElement);
            }
            else
            {
                // durationMilli is not valid double - perhaps it contains letters or some special characters, report an error
            }
```

Comment: Convert it to an double before passing it a function that wants a double?

Comment: The variable durationMilli should not be of type `string`. It should be (as evidenced by the exception message you showed) of type `double`.

Comment: It's exactly like the error is telling you: FromMilliseconds() is expecting a double, but you are giving it a string. You'll have to turn it into a double before you can use it like that. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1.aspx

Comment: pass a double not a string in the FromMilliseconds().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

durationMilli is a string. To try to convert it to double use

```
string durationMilli=DurationValue[1].TrimStart();
double milliseconds;
// Try to convert string to double
if (double.TryParse(durationMilli, out milliseconds))
{
   // milliseconds now contains your value

   TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(milliseconds);
   xmlElement.InnerText = DurationValue[1].TrimStart();
   newChild.AppendChild(xmlElement);
}
else
{
   // durationMilli is not valid double - perhaps it contains letters or some special characters, report an error
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As the error message indicates, the method accepts an argument of type `double`. As there is no implicit conversion from `string` to `double`, yes, you need to convert string representation to a number.

There are several ways to accomplish the conversion. You can use [`double.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.parse.aspx) or [`double.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse.aspx), for example, to convert the `string` to a `double`.

Answer (score 2):

```
    string durationMilli=DurationValue[1].TrimStart();
```

try making this line

```
    double durationMilli= Convert.ToDouble(DurationValue[1].TrimStart());
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use any of the following methods to convert a `string` into a `double`: `Convert.ToDouble()`, `double.TryParse()`, or `double.Parse()`.